# Reshape W to plot component images: sklearn NMF output from decomposition of 3D numpy array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, decomposition, nmf

I need help to plot the output of sklearn decomposition.NMF.

The original `data` is an image stack (3D numpy array) with dimensions `z,y,x = 46,974,1414`.

`data` is reshaped for input to the sklearn NMF decomposition. `data_r=data.reshape(-1,z)`, so `data_r.shape = (1377236, 46)`

```
estimator = decomposition.NMF(n_components = n_components, init = 'random')    
W = estimator.fit_transform(data_r)
H = estimator.components_
```

To plot the image of component 0 I try `plt.imshow(W.reshape(y,x,n_components)[:,:,0])`.
This seems to tile the images in the [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5FB3.jpg), atleast I have not been able to reshape and plot the dimensions I want... Could anyone help out with this? Datasets to practice on can be found here https://doi.org/10.15131/shef.data.17081228.v1

Comment: What is the value of `n_components`?

Comment: Also, your input data are a tiff stack, is this why you reshape to a 2D before the NNMF? Is this valid? Sorry I don't understand the NNMF.

Comment: n_components is short for the number of components to separate into. It can be anything >1.

Comment: The input has to be 2D for sklearn NMF. Don't ask me why 